# Variables between List

Tags: sencha-touch-2

My problem is... I have a list who is completed by a store and this store comes from a proxy (json). When i clik in a item of the list i need a detail information, and this detail information comes from anothe json.

For example:

ArtistList and ArtistDetail

When i click in an item of artistList i need a call to

```
http://localhost/json-detail/45
```

if i click in another item...

```
http://localhost/json-detail/50 etc...
```

My problem is that i can't send the parameter to the other view... or maybe the error is in my concept of lists... :S

This is my list view:

```
var listaArtistas = {
        xtype: 'list',
        title: 'Artistas',
        height: 240,
        store: {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['node'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'http://localhost/json-artistas',

                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'nodes'
                }
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            itemtap: function(lista,index,target,record,e,eOpts)
            {

                var artistDetail = new Ext.create('app.view.ArtistDetail');
                artistDetail.setArtistID('45');
                panelHomeNav.push(artistDetail);

            }
        },

        itemTpl: tpl

        };
```

This is my detail:

```
Ext.define('app.view.ArtistDetail',{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'artistdetail',
style: "background-image:url('/resources/images/fondoartista.png');",

config:{
    title: 'Artistas',
    iconCls: 'star',
    ArtistID: '',
    items:
    {
        title: 'Artistas',
        items: [artistDetailPanelContenedor]
    }
}});
```

And need something like this

```
var listaEspectaculo = {
        xtype: 'list',
        title: 'Artistas',
        store:
        {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['node'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'http://localhost/json-artistasdetail/'+getArtistID, <<<<<<<<<<------ PROBLEM

                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'nodes'
                }
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            itemtap: function(lista,index,target,record,e,eOpts)
            {
                var eventDetail = new Ext.create('app.view.EventDetail');
                panelHomeNav.push(eventDetail);                 
            }
        },          
        itemTpl: tplEspectaculo

};
```

THx for help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:
[How to pass value from controller to data store in sencha touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014499/how-to-pass-value-from-controller-to-data-store-in-sencha-touch)

```
handler: function () {
    Ext.dispatch({
        controller: MyApp.controllers.controller,
        action: 'myActionOnController',
        id: e.get{'id'}
    });
}
```

You can call ext.dispatch from your "itemtap", then in the controller you can call a new view with you parameters, remember use something like this:

```
myActionOnController: function (options) {
    var city = options.id; //if you want to use your parameters
    var newView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.viewOfSomething');
    this.getMain().push(newView);
},
```